# Creating Entities from MySQL Database

Tags: symfony, annotations, yaml, reverse

Having created yaml-metadata from my existing, large (over 100 entities) MySQL- database, I would like to create php entity classes WITHOUT the annotations. In my understanding, one can only use ONE of the three possible formats. I use yaml and don't want to have to delete all the annotation lines in the php entity files.

Am I missing something? Is there a parameter that accomplishes this? Here is my entity creation command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle --path ./src
```

Comment: what are you getting for the command mentioned in you question ?

Comment: Been awhile since I have used generate entities.  This link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html seems to suggest using doctrine:mappings:import followed by doctrine:mappings:convert

Answer (score 0):

To start with - thanks for your attention! See below what I get from the entity creation process as described in the docu. Everything is (more or less!) fine, except - as I see it - I don't only get the metadata description in yaml-format (which is what I want), but in addition also the annotation lines in the created entity php-files. Maybe I miss something, but my "entry-level" knowledge of Symfony makes me suspect that producing the annotation lines is superfluous. I would like it to be suppressed - if possible.

```
--------------------------------
file src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Vips.orm.yml
-------------------------------
AppBundle\Entity\Vips:
    type: entity
    table: vips
    indexes:
        persNr:
            columns:
                - persNr
        codeKat:
            columns:
                - codeKat
    uniqueConstraints:
        nummer:
            columns:
                - nummer
    id:
        nummer:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
        datvon:
            type: date
            nullable: false
            options:
                default: '1999-09-01'
            id: true
            column: datVon
    fields:
        vvip:
            type: smallint
            nullable: true
            options:
                unsigned: false
                default: '0'
            column: vVip
        spezbeh:
    ....

-------------------------------
file src/AppBundle/Entity/vips.php
-------------------------------
<?php

  namespace AppBundle\Entity;

  /**
   * Vips
   **/
  class Vips
{

 /**
  * @var integer
  */
   private $nummer;

 /**
   * @var \DateTime
  */
private $datvon = '1999-09-01';

 /**
  * @var integer
  */
 private $vvip = '0';

 /**
  * @var integer
  */
 private $spezbeh = '0';
 ...
```